# Как использовать прокси в TLSharp?

Tags: c#, tlsharp

Вот мой основной код. Использую последнюю версию TLSharp для авторизации в Telegram. Искал в интернете информацию, но не нашел. Документации у библиотеки как таковой нет. Подскажите, как подключаться к Telegram через прокси в этом случае?

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TeleSharp.TL;
using TeleSharp.TL.Contacts;
using TLSharp.Core;
using System;
using TeleSharp.TL.Messages;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using TLSharp.Core.Network;
using TLSharp.Network;

namespace TelegramT
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            int api_id = 111111;
            string api_hash = "nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn";

            var client = new TelegramClient(api_id, api_hash);
            await client.ConnectAsync();
            if (!client.IsUserAuthorized())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("BAD - Client not authorized");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OK - Client authorized");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Либо, быть может, кто пользуется другими библиотеками для работы с Telegram в C# - подскажите их.

Comment: [Проект есть на гитхабе](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp), в списке issue [поищите](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+proxy) по слову прокси, например [вот](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/issues/824) - не похоже на ответ?

Comment: У TelegramClient нет сейчас свойства handler